# What is the latest version of eosio and what is the new github site?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code, eosio.token, docker

Why is the official github no longer updated last year?
How do I build the latest image?

Answer (score 3):

EOSIO was taken over by the [EOS Network Foundation](https://eosnetwork.com/) and block.one, the company that initially developed the EOSIO framework stopped development and archived the repositories in [github.com/eosio](https://github.com/EOSIO).

EOSIO is now Antelope [(see Antelope.io)](http://antelope.io/) and further developed by the EOS Network Foundation. In addition a Coallition of multiple Antelope-based chains has been formed.

You can find the latest developments and maintained Repositories in [github.com/antelopeio](https://github.com/antelopeIO), the "leap"-repository is what previously was the eosio-repository, containing code and build instructions for programs like nodeos, cleos, keosd etc.